# How to manipulate data objects and arrays using Laravel Map function?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, highcharts

Code:

```
$loans = Loan::select('date_release')
               ->where('invalid',false)
               ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
               ->get()
               ->groupBy(function($date) {
        
           return Carbon::parse($date->date_release)->format('m'); // grouping by months
    });

    $loanmcount = [];
    $loanArr = [];

    foreach ($loans as $key => $value) {
        $loanmcount[(int)$key] = count($value);
    }

    for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
        if(!empty($loanmcount[$i])){
            $loanArr[$i] = $loanmcount[$i];    
        }else{
            $loanArr[$i] = 0;    
        }
    }

$loanTypeCount = Loan::select(['loan_type AS name', DB::raw('count(loan_type) AS y')])
                     ->groupBy('loan_type')
                     ->orderBy(DB::raw('y'), 'desc')
                     ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
                     ->where('invalid', false)
                     ->get(); 

$loanTypeCount->map(function($loan)use($loanArr) {    
    $loan->data = $loanArr;
    return $loan;
})
```

**Output:**

```
var_dump(json_encode($loanTypeCount));
```

`string(433) "[{"name":"Salary","y":"6","data":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2,"6":1,"7":3,"8":1,"9":1,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1","data":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2,"6":1,"7":3,"8":1,"9":1,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}}]"`

**Months were represented by numbers instead of month name.** Also, the format is not in array form just like the desired output shown below.

**Desired Output:**

```
  [
        {
            name: "Salary",
            y: "1",
            data: [
                [
                    "January",
                    0.1
                ],
                [
                    "February",
                    1.3
                ],
                
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Emergency",
            y: "2",
            data: [
                [
                    "March",
                    0.1
                ],
                [
                    "April",
                    1.3
                ],
                
            ]
        }
  ]
```

What is the solution for this one? Can't figure this out. Please help. THank you.

Answer (score 2):

in PHP the function has a private scope ,so you can't access the variable normally inside a function.you have to manually pass it to the function
try:

```
$loanTypeCount->map(function ($loan) use ($loanArr) {    
        $loan->data = $loanArr;
        return $loan;
    });
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clear, the error was gone but the format of data isn't matching the desired output.

Comment: I edited the solution ,you want the response as an array but it you make it associative array which be an object in json format not an array

Comment: It says  Undefined Offset: 1 on this line: array_push($loanArr,array($loanArr[$i],0));

Comment: sorry about that ,could you show me how  ```$loanmcount```  looks like

Comment: array(5) { [9]=> int(1) [5]=> int(2) [6]=> int(1) [7]=> int(3) [8]=> int(1) }